# How can I send a request from Thingsboard dashboard to multi devices?

Tags: thingsboard

i want send a request from Thingsboard dashboard to multi devices, but i couldn't!

my question is how can i send a request to multi devices from Thingsboard dashboard?

i use this setting in entity aliases , but just work for one device[image]